# get content inside html not working

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to extract the html content from inside a website. I want only the content inside the  tags.

```
    //$validLink is a link with .htm extension, source code is rather large 
    //contains 24,000 lines of html code

    $thehtml = file_get_contents($validlink);
    $thehtml = preg_match("/<body.*?>(.*?)<\/body>/is", $thehtml);
```

What else can I do? $thehtml is empty.... I am trying to insert this into a wordpress post... but $thehtml is empty.... for some odd reason. Is there a possible timeout issue or something???

There can't be a timeout issue..... due to the fact that I noticed that if I output just file_get_contents($validlink); for some reason BODY is not found.....

Another possible solution would be just to get the content between the first div and the last div found in the document....

Comment: Use a DOM parser, not regexp, to extract information from HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the string position using 'strpos()' of both tag starting and ending then use sub string method i.e, substr() with this positions

Comment: Thanks I was able to make a word around and use the substr() and strpos() etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$thehtml = file_get_contents($validlink);
$thehtml = preg_match("/<body.*?>(.*?)<\/body>/is", $thehtml,$matches);
$thehtml = $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code:

```
$thehtml = file_get_contents($validlink);
preg_match('/<body.*?>(.*?)<\/body>/is', $thehtml, $matches);
$thehtml = $matches[1];
```

But I suggest you to use [DOM parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml) instead.

Comment: how would you do it with DOM Parser? $thehtml = file_get_contents($validlink); $dumphtml = $thehtml->find('body')->innertext;  ???